Frequency polygon for a continuous distribution
What happens if we build a frequency polygon for a continuous distribution, as for a discrete one (that is, each value of the sample will correspond to its frequency of occurrence in this sample)?
By plotting on Python, I got a straight line with a value of $\frac{1}{size}$ ($size$ is a size of sample), that is, such a value corresponds to each sample value (I tried to do this for uniform continuous and normal distributions). I think that such a situation will develop with any continuous distribution (because the values are scattered with the same probability and there are infinitely many of them in the interval), however, two questions from my teacher made me doubt the results I received:

"Will there always be a straight line?"
"When is it possible/applicable to build a polygon is the frequency distribution for continuous distribution exactly as described above, and not as it is usually done (a line is drawn connecting the midpoints of the histogram columns)?"

Please help me figure out these questions (the second question, I think, follows from the first one). It just seems to me that the situation I described is true for any continuous distribution, but the teacher's question made me doubt it.
